# Using hooks from a nested componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to integrate hooks with some legacy React code. My old react code triggers a callback from a componentDidMount. I wanted to use a hook in the callback to update some state, but that doesnt seem to work: the hook gets stuck with the original value. Here's a pared down, reproducible example:

https://jsfiddle.net/0yf2xm96/16/

```
const Test = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  
    return (
    <div>
      <Test2 onMount={() => setValue(value + 1)} />
      <Test2 onMount={() => setValue(value + 1)} />

      { value /* displays 1, but I'd like to see 2 */ }
    </div>
  );
}

class Test2 extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onMount();
  }
  
  render() { return null; }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

I want that to display 2, not 1 - how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to the `useState` hook that takes the previous state value as an argument, as seen in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).
Change your onMount to:

```
<Test2 onMount={() => setValue(prev=>prev + 1)} />
<Test2 onMount={() => setValue(prev=>prev + 1)} />
```

Comment: This solves the problem but I feel like it's missing a *why*. Plenty of times I can go ahead and do `setValue(value + 1)` and it works just fine. React does it in their first example of hooks, for instance: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html Why is my code here different?

Comment: Haha yep, pasted the wrong link. I believe your 2nd onMount function is being called before the state has time to be set to 1, so its just adding 1 to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, I suggest you to modify your code like this:

```
const Test = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  
  
    return (
    <div>
      <Test2 onMount={() => setValue(value => value + 1)} />
      <Test2 onMount={() => setValue(value => value + 1)} />

      { value }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Explanation: you know hook are async and if you call just `setValue(value + 1)` you are not considering the previous value of `value`. Bu tif you use arrow funcition the problem will be solved.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/y2mgfeak/3/) your code modified.

Comment: Going to copy my comment on the other answer: This solves the problem but I feel like it's missing a *why*. Plenty of times I can go ahead and do `setValue(value + 1)` and it works just fine. React does it in their first example of hooks, for instance: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html Why is my code here different?

Comment: Ciao @thedayturns, I'm not the maximum expert of arrow function and the only thing I know is what I wrote on answer: `setValue(value + 1)` does not consider the previous value of `value`. it just try to increment value to 1. Considering that hook are async, if you call 2 times `setValue(value + 1)` like your example, both calls is getting the initial value of `value` (0). On the other hand, call 2 times  `setValue(value => value + 1)` is different because each call now takes in consideration the previuos value of `value`. So they are sequentialized we could say.

Comment: Its actually not an async issue. Its a stale closure issue. The class based `setState` is what you're referring to. To be fair, they have almost the exact same behavior, but for different reasons.

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Value is "stale". Use a functional update.

---

## What's causing the problem

Lets think about this in plain javascript terms first.

`Test` is a function. Yes, its a component so it gets used like a special function with special JSX syntax, but ultimately its just a function.

With that understanding, we can also understand that `value`, while it is part of a `useState` hook, is just a javascript variable. In fact, its a `const` which means its value cannot be changed after it has been declared. I think this is a misunderstanding that most people have about the `useState` hook - just because it's stateful does not mean it can abandon the rules of being a `const`.

When you call a `useState` updater, it will signal React that the component needs to re-render. **This re-render may not happen immediately**. When the component is re-rendered, the function `Test` is called again. The implications of this are that a **new** `const` called `value` is created. The new `const` is assigned the value passed from the `useState` updater. This is what makes the hook so powerful. Setting state is not a simple variable assignment, it is a way to maintain values through multiple function calls.

Back to the issue:
When you declare two arrow functions like you did here:

```js
<Test2 onMount={() => setValue(value + 1)} />
<Test2 onMount={() => setValue(value + 1)} />
```

You can hopefully now see that `value` in both of these functions is 0. Even after the first function is called, `value` is a `const` and still retains the value 0. Both functions get called before the next render cycle, which means the second one to be called is victim to `value` going stale.

## Solution

Use the callback version of setting state referred to as [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). Most people eventually figure out the solution whether they understand *why* or not. When using the updater form, the value of state passed into the callback function is always guaranteed to use the most recent version, thereby removing the issue.